# ArrayList losing values?

Tags: java

I'm making a program that checks if a game of tic-tac-toe is a win or not.
I keep getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Here is my code:

```
public class J1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    J1 prog = new J1();
    prog.run(args);
}


ArrayList<Integer> board = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int[] checkPattern = {0, 1, 2, 3, 6};

void run(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> board = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        String[] line = in.nextLine().split(" ");

        for(String x : line){
            if(x.equals("X")){
                board.add(0);
            } else if(x.equals("O")){
                board.add(1);
            } else {
                board.add(-1);
            }

        }

    }

    System.out.println(board);

    for(int x : checkPattern){
        if(checkPos2(x)){
            System.out.println("YES");
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("NO");

}

boolean checkPos2(int index){
    int current = board.get(index);
    return false;
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
int current = board.get(index);
```

It seems that my `board` array has elements before I call `checkPos2(x)` but when I call it they are gone. I've tried searching around but to no avail. Any insight into what's happening is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It might be helpful if you would add some example input to test your program with.

Comment: Have you checked the size of your list after you get done populating it?  Do all values of the index throw the exception, or only a specific one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `run` method, you have this line:

```
ArrayList<Integer> board = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

That declares a local variable named `board` which masks your class variable `board`. All of the changes you make inside of `run` only affect that local value, leaving the field `board` untouched. Then `checkPos2` tries to read a value from the field, which is still empty.

Just remove the declaration in `run` entirely (since the field is fully initialized already), and the issue will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I cant believe I missed that when I checked over it. I'm such an idiot x_x Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no reason for using an ArrayList.
For my school, i am writing an exam, exactly about this topic and 
i just got a bit of code which works perfectly fine and I'll just post it here     for you and explain it.

```
public class Feld implements Cloneable{

private int value;   //0 = kein Stein 1 = Team weiß 2 = Team schwarz   (0 by default)


public Feld() {

}

public Feld(int v) {
    this.setValue(v);
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void negate(){
    value = -value;
}

public void setValueWithoutRangeCheck(int value){
    this.value = value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    if(inrange(value))
        this.value = value;
}

private boolean inrange(int value) {
    return (value >= -1 && value <= 1);
}

public Feld clone() {
    return new Feld(value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Feld{" + "value=" + value + '}';
}

}
```

This is my field class (German "Feld"). You should just rename it.
each field got a value. inrange checks if the value is -1,0,1 (can be used for teamA, nothing, teamB (for example). Negate just changes the value of the field (1 to -1 for example). If you going to create a KI, you need to clone this Object (if you want to know how to write a KI in TIC TAC TOE i can explain it to you (just send me an email to finn.eggers@gmx.de)

My Seccond class is my actuall array:

```
public class FeldArray implements Cloneable{
private Feld[][] felder;


public class FeldArrayIterator{

    private FeldArray array;
    private int currentX;
    private int currentY;

    protected FeldArrayIterator(FeldArray array,int x, int y){
        this.array = array;
        this.currentX = x;
        this.currentY = y;
    }

    public void goTo(int x, int y){
        this.currentX = x;
        this.currentY = y;
    }

    public void next(int x, int y) {
        this.currentX = this.currentX + x;
        this.currentY = this.currentY + y;
    }

    public int getCurrentX() {
        return this.currentX;
    }

    public int getCurrentY() {
        return this.currentY;
    }

    public void next() {
        this.currentX ++;
        if(this.getCurrent() == null){
            this.currentX = 0;
            this.currentY ++;
        }
    }

    public Feld getCurrent() {
        return array.getFeld(currentX, currentY);
    }

}


public FeldArrayIterator iterator() {
    return new FeldArrayIterator(this,0,0);
}

public FeldArray(int size){
    this.resetFeld(size);
}


public int getAmountOf(int i){
    int lsg = 0;
    FeldArrayIterator it = this.iterator();
    while(it.getCurrent() != null){
        if(it.getCurrent().getValue() == i){
            lsg ++;
        }
        it.next();
    }
    return lsg;
}

public int getSize() {
    return this.felder.length;
}

private void resetFeld(int size) {
    felder = new Feld[size][size];
    for(int i = 0; i < this.getSize(); i++){
        for(int n = 0; n < this.getSize(); n++){
            this.setFeld(new Feld(), i, n);
        }
    }
}

private Feld getFeld(int x, int y) {
    if(inrange(x,y))
        return this.felder[x][y];
    else{
        return null;
    }
}

private void setFeld(Feld f, int x, int y){
    if(inrange(x,y))
        this.felder[x][y] = f;
} 

public void setValue(int value,int x, int y){
    if(inrange(x,y))
        this.getFeld(x, y).setValue(value);
}

public int getValue(int x, int y) {
    if(inrange(x,y)){
        return this.getFeld(x, y).getValue();
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

public FeldArray clone() {
    FeldArray array = new FeldArray(this.getSize()); 
    for(int i = 0; i < this.getSize(); i++){
        for(int n = 0; n < this.getSize(); n++){
            array.setFeld(this.getFeld(i, n).clone(), i, n);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public String toString() {
    String res = "FeldArray\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < this.getSize(); i++){
        for(int n = 0; n < this.getSize(); n++){
            res += this.getValue(n,i)+" ";
        }
        res += "\n";
    }
    res += "-----------------";
    return res;
}
private boolean inrange(int x, int y) {
    return (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < this.getSize() && y < this.getSize());
}
}
```

This on just creates an array, its not possible to get any value outside the array. So there cant be thrown any exceptions)

Also i implemented an iterator.
If you dont know what it is, i'll just explain it:

You can create a new iterator by calling: youArray.iterator().
This returns a new Iterator from the type FeldArrayIterator
This Iterator has a field and by calling getCurrent(), you get the actuall
element of the array, the iterator is pointing at.
By calling next(). It goes to the next element in the Array.
So when you want to get every element of the Array you just need to call:

```
FeldArrayIterator it = array.iterator();
while(it.getCurrent() != null) {
    //doSomething
    it.next();
}
```

Actually its quit easy. but never forget it.next().

By calling it.next(x,y). You can go to any element relativ to your position.
So if your current position is (1,2) and you say it.next(2,2). Your current position is (3,4).

I hope i could have helped you with this.